# Bootstrap 3 tag list with input group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tags, bootstrap-tags-input

I try to make a tag list (like in stackoverflow) using a [bootstrap 3 input group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups).

The result should look similar to this with a full height button on the right:

[image: should look similar to this]

The base for my considerations looks like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my attempt to make a tag list out of it (please note that it should have multiple lines)

HTML:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="form-control">
            <ul>
                <li><span class="label label-default">Default</span></li>
                <li><span class="label label-primary">Primary</span></li>
                <li><span class="label label-success">Success</span></li>
                ... even more labels ...
                <li><span class="label label-default">Default</span></li>
                <li><span class="label label-primary">Primary</span></li>
                <li><span class="label label-success">Success</span></li>
            </ul>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Running demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bc3yh42k/)

However, that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Can you show me the image of the result you want please?

Comment: @vee sorry, I don't have an image. something like [this](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) with a button on the right would be fine however.

Comment: It looks like you might have to remove or edit the .form-control class/div

Comment: when I remove `.form-control`, the frame disappears...

Comment: There is a huge amount of work to create your own tagging engine that is not included in the subtext of this question.  Why not use one that already exists?  If you still want to roll your own, you should give it a first go and then ask pointed questions when you get stuck.

Comment: @KyleMit you might be right but I didn't find an adequat project yet. I din't have any trouble with the tag engine itself yet (although it's not yet finished). This question is just about the design...

Comment: I think you can't just use form-control to cloak it.The Bootstrap 3 form-control contain fixed height. You have to add custom css like this... http://jsfiddle.net/bc3yh42k/1/

Answer (score 7):

To create the tag portion, you can use [**bootstrap-tagsinput** by Tim Schlechter](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) and then style it similar to [Bootstrap's Input Group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups) with some custom styling like this:

[image: Tags Input Group]

#### Demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/spvywgry/) & Stack Snippets

```css
.input-group .bootstrap-tagsinput {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    width: 100%
}
.input-group-btn {
    height: 0px;
}
.input-group-btn .btn {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>


<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" 
         class="bootstrap-tagsinput form-control" 
         data-role="tagsinput" 
         value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

---

## Dismissable Alert

If you're just trying to style a removable element, you can do that similar to [Bootstrap's Dismissable Alert](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#alerts), with some custom styling which will look like this:

[image: Alert-Tag]

#### Demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/spvywgry/) & Stack Snippets:

```css
.alert.alert-tag {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.alert-tag.alert-dismissible {
    padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in alert-tag" role="alert"> 
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
  </button> 
  Label
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! It looks promising but it doesn't work in my browser (iceweasel aka Firefox 31), see [here](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3744/riuloeft_png.htm) and [here](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3744/ijwjac4p_png.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need edit your

item for something like this:

```
<span class="tag label label-primary">Primary<span data-role=
    "remove"></span></span>
```

Add this to your css:

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 4px;
    max-width: 100%;
    line-height: 22px;
    cursor: text;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: inherit;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput input:focus {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
    margin-right: 2px;
    color: white;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"] {
    margin-left: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:after {
    content: "x";
    padding: 0px 2px;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag [data-role="remove"]:hover:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```

And... add bootstrap-tagsinput to your from-group before ul:

```
<div class="form-control bootstrap-tagsinput">
```